# Adding custom section in careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

What about a possibility of adding a custom section in the CV, something that doesn't really fit **education** or **background**, such as army service? Where I live, army service is mandatory, and I would like to have that in its own section. While this might not be exactly programming related, it could really help making better use of Careers outside the US.

**Edit:** maybe just an "Other" section with free-text.

Comment: +1: finally a place where I can put the fact that I can name every kind of donut at Tim Hortons!

Comment: There's only one kind worth naming: sour cream glazed!

Comment: I like the idea, but if it's mandatory, why list it? Won't it be like listing "breathes oxygen"?

Comment: @ceejayoz Mostly in order to list a relevant army experience, for instance, elite programming units, intelligence corps, etc.

Comment: National Service is also mandatory here.  While it's an easy enough thing to cover in a phone or face-to-face interview, giving people a place in the CV to brag about what they learned -- *other than the difference between their rifle and their gun* -- would be a nice feature.

Comment: @hmemcpy Couldn't that be listed as an entry in employment history?